# align responsive input together with image block

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to align a div block on the left of a responsive input bar.

But I have problem make it responsive, if you view on full screen it's ok but still not responsive, on smaller screen it break aparts.

```
<div class="reply_placeholder">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Click here to reply">
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/499u5ka6

Comment: If you always want to keep them side by side even in smaller devices then why don't you keep them in table ?

Comment: It would be best if you used box-sizing: border-box, and then add position: absolute to the logo and position it to the left. You then adjust the padding of the reply_placeholder container to compensate for the space taken up by the logo. Makes sense? I'm editing your fiddle now to show you what I mean,.

Comment: Take a look at this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/499u5ka6/4/ I'll post solution if it looks fine to you.

Comment: does anyone know why if you use inline-block on both the logo is aligned at the top and the input at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.logo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/200");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  float:left;
}

.reply_placeholder input {
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
}
```

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: No, what is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing `width` with `width: calc`

```
.reply_placeholder input {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% - 70px);  /*adjust the 70px as needed*/
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you're looking for is to first use `box-sizing: border-box;` In the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/499u5ka6/5/

I added border-box to everything. But you can modify your CSS to affect just `.reply_placeholder` and everything inside it so that you don't affect your entire page and site.

After applying `box-sizing: borer-box`, you would add `position: absolute` to your image, and position it using `top: 50%; left: 0`. Then change `padding-left` for `.reply_placeholder` from `30px` to `65px`. Adjust all these values as you see fit to achieve the spacing and positioning you're looking for.

Lastly, change your input field width to `100%`.

All modifications should be made to your CSS. The updated CSS is below:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.reply_placeholder {
  padding: 30px 30px 20px 65px; /* changed padding-left from 30 to 65px */

  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute; /* new */
  top: 50%; /* new */
  left: 0; /* new */
  margin-top: -20px; /* new */

  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/200");
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  display: block; /* inline-block to block */
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.reply_placeholder input {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use a background-image for logos, but if you want to do it with a div, an easy fix would be to simply set the parent to display: flex;
http://jsfiddle.net/499u5ka6/9/

```
.reply_placeholder {
    padding: 30px 30px 20px 30px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    display: flex;// add this
}
```